# How display variable value into my TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question, how can i display text from a varible in a text box?
example:

i have a system with windows form in C#, what i want to do is when a click a button, in my text box show me the variable value, i have the following code:

```
string resume = "Hello world";
txtDescription.Text = resume;
```

but in my textbox it doesn't show me the value, and i want to show me Hello world in my textbox like this:

[image]

Comment: Posted code should work.  Please post a more complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have that code after `InitializeComponent()` method, it should be working.

InitializeComponent() method initialize every component using it's designer settings. So that code should be after the initializing.

Comment: now it worked, just i putted my code after the InitializeComponent() method, thank you very much!!